# Как в phantomjs ( php-phantomjs ) установить задержку после загрузки страницы

Tags: php, phantomjs

Я использую php-phantomjs для тестирования, но после захода на страницу у меня не все скрипты успевают отработать.

Подскажите, как можно поставить задержку после того как страница была загружена, я читал доку на git hub, но ничего не нашел.

Удалось написать JS код, для задержки но пока не удалось добавить его в шаблон для работы с php - phantomjs

```
var page = require('webpage').create(); console.log((new Date).toLocaleTimeString() + " start"); page.open('http://example.com/', function() { page.evaluate(function() { }); console.log((new Date).toLocaleTimeString() + " before sleep"); setTimeout( function () { console.log((new Date).toLocaleTimeString() + " finish"); page.render('beeline.png'); phantom.exit(); }, 15000 // wait 5,000ms (5s) ); });
```

Comment: Что вы собираетесь делать с этой задержкой? Для чего она практически нужна? Пример кода бы увидеть.

Comment: Задержка - нужна что бы все ajax компоненты подгрузились потом я делаю скрин и все.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/4.0/3-usage/#on-load-finished) можно воспользоваться таким способом ожидания полной загрузки страницы:

```
    use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;
    $client = Client::getInstance();
    $client->isLazy(); // Tells the client to wait for all resources before 
    rendering
    $request  = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest();
    $request->setTimeout(5000);
```

Comment: Благодарю за отвте, но setTimeout устанавливает максимальное время ожидание для загрузки страницы... а не задержку...

Comment: `var page = require('webpage').create();
    console.log((new Date).toLocaleTimeString() + " start");
    page.open('http://example.com/', function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
        });
       console.log((new Date).toLocaleTimeString() + " before sleep");
     setTimeout(
      function () {
       console.log((new Date).toLocaleTimeString() + " finish");
      page.render('beeline.png');
      phantom.exit();
      },
      15000 // wait 5,000ms (5s)
     );
    });` смог сделать вот такой JS код который делает задержку

Comment: Я подозреваю что это как то надо добавить в шаблон но пока не понял как

Comment: @ff.0xff добавьте код в вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы скрипты на странице успели загрузится, я поступаю следующим образом:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();

page.open("http://my_url", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // код, который должен выполнятся после полной загрузки страницы
  }, 1000); // задержка
});
```